# Backup Script Failure After Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: bash, backup

For years I've backed up my system to an external hard drive using a shell script with a simple copy command like

cp -uvR Documents/* "/media/myUserName/MyBackupDevice/Documents/"

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20.04.1, my script will only update files that already exist on the backup device. Where the destination file does not yet exist, no file is created and the copy fails with a message like:

cp: cannot create regular file '/media/myUserName/MyBackupDevice/Documents/Rest/of/Path/FileName.pdf': Invalid argument

Depending on which files I've modified, sometimes a directory to which the script could not write a new file is the same directory in which it could update a pre-existing file.

Any suggestions on how to adapt my script?

Comment: I would use rsync instead: `rsync -zav /path/to/Documents/ /media/myUserName/MyBackupDevice/Documents`

Comment: That did not help. All attempts to copy a file not present in the destination directory results in an error like this: rsync: mkstemp "/path/to/file.pdf.LvTfoQ" failed: Invalid argument (22).  The man page for rsync says that a 22 error means "Error allocating core memory buffers" but I don't know what that means.

Comment: I think it has something to do with permissions - which filesystem is on the external drive?

Comment: The file system on the external drive is fuse. However, it seems that the problem with rsync is that most of my files have a colon in the filename, so it looks like I have to rename thousands of files before I can use rsync or figure out why cp (which worked well with filenames with colons in Ubuntu 18) suddenly failed after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Hmm yes "invalid" characters in the filename could be the reason. I don't know the history of using `:` in the filename, and how this relates to Ubuntu 18 vs. Ubuntu 20.